# Error in INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a script that uploads an image to a server, and the path to a MySQL Database. When I submit this it comes up with this error:

> error in INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path') VALUES
>   ('images/05-12-2014-1417785023.png') == ----> You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ''images_tbl'
>   ('images_path') VALUES ('images/05-12-2014-1417785023.png')' at line 1

Here is the code:

```
<?php
 include("mysqlconnect.php");

     function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
         {
        if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
        switch($imagetype)
        {
            case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
            case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
            case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
            case 'image/png': return '.png';
            default: return false;
        }
      }



 if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

     $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
     $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
     $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
     $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
     $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
     $target_path = "images/".$imagename;


 if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

      $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path') VALUES ('".$target_path."')";
     mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  

 }else{

    exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
 } 

 }

?>
```

My editor is not bringing up any syntax errors, but it seems to suggest there is in that error.

Comment: as stated in the error, its a mysql error

Comment: @Alex Walker-Ingham Don't use mysql_, instead use mysqli_* or PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifier quotes are backticks not single quotes:

```
INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path')
            ^           ^             ^
```

You could just ditch them instead.

```
INSERT into images_tbl (images_path)
// or
INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`)
```

Obligatory Note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
>
> <sub>Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860140/3859027</sub>

Here's a short example of a mysqli usage:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$query_upload = 'INSERT INTO images_tbl (images_path) VALUES (?)';
$insert = $db->prepare($query_upload);
$insert->bind_param('s', $target_path);
$insert->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be -

```
"INSERT into images_tbl (images_path) VALUES ('".$target_path."')";
```

OR

```
"INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`) VALUES ('".$target_path."')";
```

Remove the `'`s. It is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying table name as simple string. Replace ' with ` or remove it at all.

```
INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`) VALUES
```

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the table name as string.

```
 $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path') VALUES ('".$target_path."')";
```

Try the code below

```
 $query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl ('images_path') VALUES ('".$target_path."')";
```

Hope this helps you.